# To-Do list with edit button Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, edit

I'm trying to make a to-do list with an edit button, that when clicked, will make added items editable, but am having trouble.  I have the button created and everything, but when I click it nothing happens.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

JavaScript

```
function editItem(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if (!parent.hasClass('edit')) {
        parent.addClass('edit');
    }else if (parent.hasClass('edit')) {    
        var editTask = $(this).prev('input[type="text"]').val();
        var editLabel = parent.find('label');
        editLabel.html(editTask);
        parent.removeClass('edit');
    }

$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'edit', editItem)
});
```

Comment: You are using `"edit"` as the selector, it selects `<edit></edit>` elements. Do you have such elements in your document?

Comment: good call @Vohuman; you might want to try `.edit` for things with the _class_ `edit`

Comment: Hi, i tried that, but it didn't seem to work.  I created a JSFiddle, could you check it out and see whats going wrong?  Thanks, guys!
https://jsfiddle.net/Rassisland/gv0qkrpp/

Comment: @praveen Kumar thanks for the help!  I'm going to go through it later, but might have some questions!  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are targeting `<edit>`, you are supposed to use `.edit`:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', editItem);
});
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  function addItem () {
    // append to the list
    $("#todo-items").append('<li><span>' + $("#todo").val() + '</span> <small><a href="#edit">Edit</a> &bull; <a href="#delete">Delete</a></small></li>');
    // clear the text
    $("#todo").val("");
  }
  $("#todo").keydown(function (e) {
    // if enter key pressed
    if (e.which == 13)
      addItem();
  });
  // on clicking the add button
  $("#add").click(addItem);
  // delegate the events to dynamically generated elements
  // for the edit button
  $(document).on("click", 'a[href="#edit"]', function () {
    // make the span editable and focus it
    $(this).closest("li").find("span").prop("contenteditable", true).focus();
    return false;
  });
  // for the delete button
  $(document).on("click", 'a[href="#delete"]', function () {
    // remove the list item
    $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(function () {
      $(this).remove();
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; text-decoration: none;}
input, li {padding: 3px;}
#todo-items small {display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px; padding: 2px; vertical-align: bottom;}
#todo-items span:focus {background-color: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="todo" />
<input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />
<ul id="todo-items"></ul>
```

Comment: Oh, i see!  This was wrong, but clicking the edit button is still resulting in nothing.  I added a JSFiddle, maybe that will help you?  Thanks!

Comment: @Rassisland Sure I will try to check it out.

Comment: @Rassisland I have updated your code buddy.. There was a lot of mistakes: https://jsfiddle.net/9v5dwxLv/

Comment: I really appreciate the help!  I'm still not seeing the edit button working though; am I missing something?

Comment: @Rassisland Kindly tell me what you are trying to achieve, I will really feel happy to recreate it in my own way and explain, rather than debugging yours. `:)` You have a lot of errors.

Comment: haha, I appreciate the help!  I'm new to coding so learn a lot from others online.  I am hoping for, when the edit button is clicked, the added item textbox will become editable, and pressing enter after editing the text box will save changes made to that box. Let me know if you need more info!  Any explanation of what you are doing would be great too!

Comment: Thanks for all the help, my code is looking a lot better now!  I am having trouble getting the edit button to format correctly though.  I'd like the button to update the new text and exit the edit option when enter is clicked, but now it skips to a new line instead.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Rassisland What new line?

Comment: when I'm in the edit text area and hit enter, I'd like the edit box to stop becoming editable.  But currently, when you hit enter it just startes a new line of editing below the current line and moves the "edit" and "delete" buttons down.

Comment: @Rassisland Ah crap. I forgot.. LoL. Just give this line: `$("ul li span").keydown(function (e) { if (e.which == 13) return false; });` Let me know if you have further issues.

Comment: Great!  You have really helped me out with this.  I appreciate it!

Comment: where do I add this line?  within the edit function?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to add a button that will delete all "Checked" items, but can't seem to get it.  Any ideas?  Thanks again, Praveen!
https://jsfiddle.net/Rassisland/5ak1thco/